# Merge arrays with unequal number of columns

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have around 100 1D arrays I'd like to merge to a matrix.
The arrays have 140 to 180 columns.

Is it possible to merge these 1 x (140-180) arrays to a matrix with a dimension of 100 (amount of arrays) x 180 ?

All the arrays contain numbers. I want to expand the 1x140 array to a 1x180 array by means of interpolation.

In a simplified form, it should be something like this:

```
A = [1 5 7 8 3]
B = [1 3 5]

result=
```

[1 5 7 8 3

1 2 3 4 5]

The array B (1x3) is expanded to an 1x5 matrix. And the values in between are interpolated.

Basically, I thought of using "vertcat" after all arrays are expanded by a same amount of columns.

Thanks in advance,
Koen

Comment: To expand `B`, do you interpolate between its min and max? Or how do you define the interpolation?

Comment: How do you know which values to interpolate between? For instance, say if `B = [1 2 5]`, what should the second row of results be? Is `B = [1 4 5 1] possible? If so, what do you want to do with it?

Comment: That's correct. If a value needs to be inserted, it should be interpolated between it's neighbours.

Comment: @user2953022: But how do you know which values to insert between? What do you do if `B = [1 4 5 1]`? And why? What is the logic behind it?

Comment: if B = [1 2 5], then the expanded B (1x5) should be [1 1.5 2 3.5 5]

Comment: @user2953022: What if `A` is 1x180, and `B` is 1x179, where would you put that last value? And if `B` is 1x140, where should they be? You need to be more specific...

Comment: @RobertP I think a meaningful way to do that is linear interpolation. However, that modifies all the values, in general

Comment: @ Robert P. I see what you mean, and probably I am wrong in presenting what I want. I want my arrays to be rescaled to a fixed amount of columns. If it's more easy to rescale to the array with the least amount of columns, that's good too.

Comment: @ Luis Mendo: correct. Modification of values is allowed.

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
array = {[1 5 7 8 3],[1 3 5]}; % example data
N = 5; % desired length (180 in your case)

aux = cellfun(@(v) interp1(linspace(0,1,length(v)),v,linspace(0,1,N)), array, 'uni', false);
result = cat(1,aux{:});
```

It uses linear interpolation. For your example, this gives

```
>> result

result =

     1     5     7     8     3
     1     2     3     4     5
```

Note that linear interpolation modifies all values of the vector except first and last, in general. For example, with `N=5` the vector `[1 3 4 5]` would get interpolated to `[1 2.5 3.5 4.25 5]`. You could use other forms of interpolation by passing an extra argument to `interp1`, see `help interp1`.